# DelegateEndpointDefinition IsTemporary

Tags: masstransit

I have a simple ConsumerDefinition:

```
public class HealthCheckConsumerDefinition : ConsumerDefinition<LoopbackConsumer>
    {
        public HealthCheckConsumerDefinition(IOptions<HealthCheckOptions> options)
        {
            EndpointName = options.Value.HostName;                
            Endpoint(configurator => configurator.Temporary = true); // not work
        }

        protected override void ConfigureConsumer(IReceiveEndpointConfigurator endpointConfigurator, IConsumerConfigurator<LoopbackConsumer> consumerConfigurator)
        {                
            endpointConfigurator.ConfigureConsumeTopology = false;
            base.ConfigureConsumer(endpointConfigurator, consumerConfigurator);
        }
    }
```

I expect the Temporary=true property to configure an endpoint with the AutoDelete = true and Durable = false properties, because this code is in the ApplyEndpointDefinition method of the RabbitMqHostConfiguration class:
https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/5fb6b4e31582970b0571e9fe6ac77793a0b3242a/src/MassTransit.RabbitMqTransport/Configuration/Configuration/RabbitMqHostConfiguration.cs#L60

```
    public void ApplyEndpointDefinition(IRabbitMqReceiveEndpointConfigurator configurator, IEndpointDefinition definition)
            {
                if (definition.IsTemporary)
                {
                    configurator.AutoDelete = true;
                    configurator.Durable = false;
                }
                ...
             }
```

But in the ConfigureEndpoints method of the class, the ConsumerDefinition registry is converted to the DelegateEndpointDefinition, which does not override the IsTemporary property based on the ConsumerDefinition object passed to the constructor:
https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/89ba77036230a15be108e8ade3a0e6fe5309a94d/src/MassTransit/Configuration/Registration/Registration.cs#L178

How to get around this problem and declare Temporary endpoint within the ConsumerDefinition?

Answer (score 1):

I have confirmed that this works as expected in the upcoming MassTransit v7 release. Using this syntax, the temporary flag is now passed through to the transport.

> Note that this would be overridden by using `.Endpoint()` following the `AddConsumer<T>()` container configuration method.

```
    class RequestConsumerDefinition :
        ConsumerDefinition<RequestConsumer>
    {
        public RequestConsumerDefinition()
        {
            Endpoint(e => e.Temporary = true);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Glad to hear that! I already saw that the commit with the fix was 27 days ago. When is v7 release expected?

Comment: Today or tomorrow.